# Communicate emacs and C++ code

Tags: c++, asynchronous, emacs, process

Is there any emacs lisp library or built-in commands to call a C++ process and receive a string of the result?

I want to call repeatdly each X seconds to a subprocess, written in C++ (which gets info of a website) and receive the process results to update a not closable horizontal emacs' buffer.

Creating a fixed buffer is not a deal, but I don't know of to "cron" an asynchronous process call and get the result (for example, connecting the start output or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell-command-to-string` is a built-in that returns the result of running a process as a string.  And `run-at-time` can be used to call it repeatedly at a certain interval, or `run-with-idle-timer` if you only want the command to run when Emacs is idle to avoid your process causing pauses in user interaction.

The elisp manual contains more information on using 
[Timers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html), [Idle Timers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html) and running [Synchronous Processes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html)